# insert dataframe to the existing csv from certain row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have an existing csv file, I want to insert more rows from the top row of the csv. It looks there is no way if using pandas.to_csv, any idea?

e.g.
existing file:

```
Date     lowprice  openprice
2018-9-28  10       11
2018-9-27  12       11.5
```

I want to insert this dataframe

```
2018-10-2  10.90    11
2018-10-1  11       12
```

into this csv so that:

```
Date     lowprice  openprice
2018-10-2  10.90    11
2018-10-1  11       12
2018-9-28  10       11
2018-9-27  12       11.5
```

Comment: one way is to read the csv into df and append the other df data on top using something like insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

- read the original data into a DataFrame
- insert the data you want to add in the correct position in the DataFrame
- write the DataFrame into a csv file

This is the only realistic way to do this; there is no way to delete or insert contents into a file, you just overwrite it with new data instead.

Comment: I thought of this and suspect it would be low efficient, considering the file becoming bigger and bigger...

Comment: Struggling for long time, it looks this is the only way with pandas.